# Restricting packages when trying to create an egg file doesnt work

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, egg

I have a python project and I want to package into an egg two packages that sit under the root of the project.

I have a setup.py *under the root* that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

packages = find_packages(include=("datainfra.*", "serverinfra.*"))

setup(
    name="infra",
    version="0.1",
    packages=packages,
)
```

The problem: I run python setup.py bdist_egg, an egg file is indeed created but it takes **all** the packages under root rather than only the ones I specified.

Naturally, I made sure the return value of find_packages contains only the desired subset.

I am running python 2.7

Comment: I created a small test package with subpackages and found it works for me as expected — the egg contains only specified subpackages. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Removing the build and `egg-info` directories and rebuilding might help.

Comment: @hoefling, blimey, This did the trick! If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup script is correct - if you are getting unexpected build results, often it results from remains of previous builds still sitting in the project directory. Removing the `<pkgname>.egg-info` directory (if the resulting package has wrong metadata), the `build` directory (if the resulting package has wrong module set) or the `.eggs` directory (if wrong setup deps keep being used in build) and rebuilding is a quick and cheap fixing attempt.